# Java Selenium: How to validate xpath?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find an element using xpath.

I tried this method:

```
    if(a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH1)) != null){
        homeTable = a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH1));
    }
    else{
        homeTable = a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH2));
    }
```

I assumed that if the first xpath won't be found, it will try he second one. But it throws an exception of element not found.

I also tried to check size = 0 instead of null, but got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method to check whether your xpath is present or not :

create a method : `isElementPresent`

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElements(by);
      return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Call it using `xpath` like this :

```
 isElementPresent(By.xpath(XPATH1));
```

So your code would become :

```
if(isElementPresent(By.xpath(XPATH1))){
        homeTable = a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH1));
    }
    else{
        homeTable = a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH2));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `findElements` instead of `findElement` and then check the size:

```
List<WebElement> elements = a_chromeWebdriver.findElements(By.xpath(XPATH1));
if(elements.size() > 0){
    homeTable = elements.get(0);
} else{
    homeTable = a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH2));
}
```

But a better way would be to combine the 2 XPath in a single one with `|`:

```
homeTable = a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH1 + "|" + XPATH2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method,

```
public WebElement getElement(By by) {
    try { 
        return a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(by);
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You could use it as follows,

```
WebElement element = getElement(By.xpath(XPATH1));
if (element == null)
    element = getElement(By.xpath(XPATH2));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First add implicit wait to your code that will handle synchronization issues 
   `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
2. Add OR Operator rather than adding condition as other answers points out. `homeTable = a_chromeWebdriver.findElement(By.xpath(XPATH1 | XPATH2));`